# Сколько байт занимает бесконечность и -бесконечность в java?

Tags: java

Сколько байт занимает бесконечность и -бесконечность в java ?

Comment: если ты про тип данных как byte, то от -128 до 127

Comment: Столько же, сколько и любое другое число типа double. Можно почитать про внутреннее представление чисел с плавающей точкой: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A7%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE_%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8

Comment: Я имею ввиду значение Infinity,которое можно занести в переменную типа double при делении любого числа на 0.0

Comment: Очевидно, бесконечность

Comment: @dIm0n Да не может она занимать бесконечность т.к. столько ресурсов быть не может.

Comment: Очень смешно,@dim0n!Так держать

Comment: @KRL я подумал, раз вы задаёте такой вопрос, то это подразумевалось. Иначе можно же доки посмотреть просто <кстати, после собаки есть автоподстановка, не надо вводить вручную ник, тогда наверняка будет уведомление, а сейчас его не было>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Бесконечность определена в типе `double` как `Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY=Double.longBitsToDouble(0x7ff0000000000000L)`, там же находится и `Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY`
2. В `float` она определена как `Float.POSITIVE_iNFiNITY=intBitsToFloat(0xff800000)`
3. В Java (и не только) `double` занимает 8 байт, `float` занимает 4 байта (согласно IEEE 754)